# Gatsby pages showing / after url

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am new at using Gatsby. I've recently developed website using it

I wanted to create pages with gatsby so I've added it in /src/pages. Pages were created but it shows / after url.

Ex. for page 'example.com/abc' it shows 'example.com/abc/' and if I try to write 'example.com/abc' in browser it redirects to 'example.com/abc/'

Extra / can be seen after url

Answer (score 2):

use gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes plugin https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes

```
npm install --save-dev gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes
```

**Then configure via gatsby-config.js.**

```
{
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...,
    `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`,
  ]
}
```